# Lists all Blobs inside Azure Container with directory-level support using web front-end

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm currently working on developing some set of codes to display all blobs inside specified Azure Container using web front-end. I'm expecting the final output to be something like this:

[image: Directory listing with Apache Mod_autoindex]

I started by creating a dummy storage account and populates it with some dummy files for me to play around with.

```
https://alicebob.blob.core.windows.net/documents  
├── docx  
│   ├── 201801_Discussion.docx  
│   ├── 201802_Discussion.docx  
├── xlsx  
│   ├── 201801_Summary.xlsx  
│   ├── 201802_Summary.xlsx  
│   ├── 201803_Summary.xlsx  
├── 201801_Review.pdf  
├── 201802_Review.pdf  
├── 201803_Review.pdf
```

To develop file listing function, I'm using Azure Storage JavaScript client library from [here](https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html) and put all the necessary codes (`.html` and `.js` files) in Azure Static website `$web` container and set `index.html` as `Index document name` and `Error document path` in the Static website configuration.

```
https://alicebob.z23.web.core.windows.net/  
├── azure-storage.blob.min.js  
├── azure-storage.common.min.js  
├── index.html
```

The problem is that the function to do the listing is only either `listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix` or `listBlobDirectoriesSegmentedWithPrefix`. So, in my case, I assume it wouldn't work straightforwardly to list all the blobs and directories in a well-structured / tree format.

My current approach is that I trick the code to keep using `listBlobDirectoriesSegmentedWithPrefix` until there is no more directory to list inside, then continue to list using `listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix`

So far I'm quite satisfied that my code can list all the Blobs at the leaf-level and also list all the directories if it isn't on the leaf-level. You can take a look at the blob listing [here](https://alicebob.z23.web.core.windows.net/) and feel free to go for **'View Source'** to see the codes I built so far.

The only problem that I face is that this set of code fails to list the Blobs if it wasn't on the leaf-level. For example, it fails to list these blobs on `alicebob` storage account:

```
├── 201801_Review.pdf  
├── 201802_Review.pdf  
├── 201803_Review.pdf
```

This is an expected issue as I'm not running `listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix` if it isn't on the leaf-level. The reason is that it will produces the output with something like this which isn't what I want:

```
├── docx/201801_Discussion.docx  
├── docx/201802_Discussion.docx  
├── xlsx/201801_Summary.xlsx  
├── xlsx/201802_Summary.xlsx  
├── xlsx/201803_Summary.xlsx  
├── 201801_Review.pdf  
├── 201802_Review.pdf  
├── 201803_Review.pdf
```

Any suggestion on how to overcome this issue? The real implementation would involves a huge amount of data so I think a simple if-then-else wouldn't be efficient on this case.

> sorry for the long description but I just want to describe my problem as clear as possible :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an option called delimiter when listing blobs. Let's get down to code.

```
blobService.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix('documents',null,null,{delimiter:'/'},(error,result,response)=>{
    console.log(result);
    console.log(response.body.EnumerationResults.Blobs.BlobPrefix);
})
```

With delimiter `/`, listing operation returns results of two parts.

1. `result`, contains info of blobs under the root directory of container, e.g. 201801_Review.pdf, etc. in your case.
2. `BlobPrefix` in response body, contains directory names of single level with delimiter.

   ```
   [ { Name: 'docx/' }, { Name: 'xlsx/' } ]
   ```

Use `BlobPrefix` as `prefix`, we can continue listing content of current subdirectory.

```
    blobService.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix('documents','docx/',null,{delimiter:'/'},(error,result,response)=>{
        console.log(result);
        console.log(response.body.EnumerationResults.Blobs.BlobPrefix);
    })
```

Basically point 1 result is enough, you don't necessarily have to use `BlobPrefix` to refactor your code. See more info in section `Using a Delimiter to Traverse the Blob Namespace` of [list blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs#remarks).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes the `delimiter` option works perfectly on my case, thanks!

Anyway for that `BlobPrefix` option I've already implemented on my code by parsing it from the URL using `getDir` function `(https://alicebob.z23.web.core.windows.net/{BlobPrefix})` so that I can continue listing the rest of the subdirectories.

Comment: @AndiAriffin You are welcome. Could you accept the answer for others to refer?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with out the overhead of the whole storage api using a fetch request as follows.

```
  fetch("https://cvworkshop.blob.core.windows.net/telaviv-bw/?restype=container&comp=list")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```